# Confused with output and answer went wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

Task PTICE, [COCI 2008/2009, Contest #1 – October 18, 2008](http://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2008_2009/contest1_tasks.pdf).

> Adrian, Bruno and Goran wanted to join the bird lovers' club. However,
>   they did not know that all  applicants must pass an entrance exam. The
>   exam consists of `N` questions, each with three possible  answers: `A`,
>   `B` and `C`.
>
> Unfortunately, they couldn't tell a bird from a whale so they are
>   trying to guess the correct answers.
>
> Each of the three boys has a theory of what set of answers will work
>   best:
>
> - Adrian claims that the best sequence is: `A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C ...`
> - Bruno is convinced that this is better: `B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C ...`
> - Goran laughs at them and will use this sequence: `C, C, A, A, B, B, C, C, A, A, B, B ...`
>
> Write a program that, given the correct answers to the exam,
>   determines who of the three was right –  whose sequence contains the
>   most correct answers.
>
> **INPUT**
>
> The first line contains an integer `N` (`1 ≤ N ≤ 100`), the number of
>   questions on the exam.  The second line contains a string of `N`
>   letters `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`. These are, in order, the correct
>   answers to the questions in the exam.
>
> **OUTPUT**
>
> On the first line, output `M`, the largest number of correct answers
>   one of the three boys gets.  After that, output the names of the boys
>   (in alphabetical order) whose sequences result in `M` correct 
>   answers.
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> *input*
>
> ```
> 5 
> BAACC
> ```
>
> *output*
>
> ```
> 3 
> Bruno
> ```
>
> *input*
>
> ```
> 9 
> AAAABBBBB
> ```
>
> *output*
>
> ```
> 4 
> Adrian 
> Bruno 
> Goran
> ```

My code:

```
my_i = input()
my_inp = raw_input()

my_dict = {
    'Adrian' : ('A','B','C')*my_i,
    'Bruno' : ('B','A','B','C')*my_i,
    'Goran' : ('C','C','A','A','B','B')*my_i
    }

my_list = []

for i in my_inp:
    i = str(i)
    my_list.append(i)

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0

for i in range(my_i):
    if my_list[i] == my_dict['Adrian'][i]:
        A += 1

    elif my_list[i] == my_dict['Bruno'][i]:
        B += 1

    elif my_list[i] == my_dict['Goran'][i]:
        C += 1

a = False
b = False
c = False
a1 = 'Adrian'
b1 = 'Bruno'
c1 = 'Goran'

if A > B and A > C:
    a = True

elif A < B and B > C:
    b = True

elif A < C and B < C:
    c = True

else:
    a,b,c = True,True,True

print A,B,C
print max(A,B,C)

if a == True:
    print a1
elif b == True:
    print b1
elif c == True:
    print c1
```

I want to know who will pass the exam.

---

*input*

```
9 
AAAABBBBB
```

*output*

```
4 
Adrian
```

I didn't get any errors but here it prints only Adrian.
Adrian = 4 Bruno = 3 Goran = 2

Comment: @Chalanthron It's not at all clear what you're asking here. To get good answers on StackOverflow, it's important that you (1) Describe what you're trying to do (2) Provide the smallest possible example of what is confusing you (3) State exactly what you expected to happen (4) Show exactly what did happen. It is not good practice to paste more than a few lines of code, here, you've added your whole script, which makes it very hard for us to help you.

Comment: If anything, the edit made things less clear. Please read through this handy checklist: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: What on earth does *"Might be this lines is wrong"* mean?! Do you get errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? What testing have you done - have you tried to `print` any values to see what's happening? Please **read** the link I just posted, and provide appropriate information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are using `elif` to compare the boys' guesses with the actual answers - what if more than one boy has the same answer correct?

Instead, make each check a separate `if`:

```
for i in range(my_i):
    if my_list[i] == my_dict['Adrian'][i]:
        A += 1
    if my_list[i] == my_dict['Bruno'][i]:
  # ^ not elif
        B += 1    
    if my_list[i] == my_dict['Goran'][i]:
  # ^ not elif
        C += 1
```

Note that you can do this with much less repetition using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import cycle

N = 5 # or int(raw_input()) - this number isn't used
answers = "BAACC" # or raw_input()

boys = {'Adrian': cycle("ABC"),
        'Bruno': cycle("BABC"),
        'Goran': cycle("CCAABB")}

scores = {boy: sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(answers, guesses))
          for boy, guesses in boys.items()}

max_score = max(scores.values())

print max_score
for boy, score in sorted(scores.items()):
    if score == max_score:
        print boy
```

By avoiding separate (and poorly-named) variables for the number of correct answers for each boy (`A`, `B` and `C`), their name (`a1`, `b1` and `c1`) and whether or not they got the largest score (`a`, `b` and `c`), this cuts down on the repeated code and makes it much easier to add additional people (with their own guessing strategies) to the dictionary.